# Drawing bitmap on canvas and imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am setting a **bitmap** to an image view using`imageView.setImageBitmap(bm)`.

Then I draw the bitmap over a canvas using `canvas.drawBitmap(bm,0,0,paint).`

Both these are displayed in entirely different ways. I want to somehow manipulate them so that both of them are displayed in the same manner.

That is same width, height and with correct aspect to fit the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainrel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".ImageMainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnzoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom" />



   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnzoom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnzoom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: then check the source code of `ImageView` you'll find that `ImageView` does some scaling based on a `Matrix`

Comment: Could you post your ImageView xml attrs?

Comment: Actually I have a custom imageview class and I add that view to the layout using layout.addView(imageView). So there is no imageview in xml. Check out the xml I have posted.